# Owl Carousel slide transitions

Tags: jquery, slide, owl-carousel

I created Owl Carousel Slider and need to do that transitions between slides be unnoticed, Move slowly and continuously.?! There is [example](https://slicejack.com/)  ( slide is in bottom of page)

If this can not do Owl Carousel Slide slider can do transitions like this slide.

Comment: post all of your code here!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/43g1c395/

Answer (score 2):

The closest I came through is minimize the difference between autoplayTimeout and smartSpeed. [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/43g1c395/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 1520,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    animateIn: 'linear',
    animateOut: 'linear'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content 1 </div>
  <div> Your Content 2</div>
  <div> Your Content 3</div>
  <div> Your Content 4</div>
  <div> Your Content 5</div>
  <div> Your Content 6</div>
  <div> Your Content 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but when slide go it roll 3 item and have small timeout i did not want that it have stop

Answer (score 0):

Just set timer to -1 like this:

```
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [clickedIndex, -1, true]);
```